# Can't pass integer value to the second Activity

Tags: android, int, android-activity, bundler

I am calling the 2nd Activity from 1st:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(MainActivity.this,  SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt(SecondActivity.ID,id);
System.out.println("id*"+id);
b.putString(SecondActivity.NAME, name);
System.out.println("name*"+name);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

LogCat:

```
11-06 19:33:57.451: I/System.out(7987): id*2
11-06 19:33:57.451: I/System.out(7987): name*MrBlack
```

2nd Activity:

```
public static final String ID = "";
public static final String NAME = "";
................
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int id = extras.getInt(ID);

System.out.println("extras.getInt(ID)*"+extras.getInt(ID));
System.out.println("extras.getString(ID)*"+extras.getString(ID));
System.out.println("extras.getString(NAME)*"+extras.getString(NAME));
TextView tvFirmaName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
tvFirmaName.setText(extras.getString(NAME));
```

LogCat:

```
11-06 19:33:57.721: I/System.out(7987): extras.getInt(ID)*0
11-06 19:33:57.731: I/System.out(7987): extras.getString(ID)*MrBlack
11-06 19:33:57.731: I/System.out(7987): extras.getString(NAME)*MrBlack
```

I do not understand why int value 2 is passing as 0
And why extras.getString(ID) is "MrBlack" value!?

Please, let me know where I was wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static final String ID = "";
public static final String NAME = "";
```

You need to provide values for those strings, they act as variable names for the info you're passing.  Their values are arbitrary, so long as they're not equal to one another.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

extras work like hashmaps. So you have to do it like:

```
b.putInt("unique key","value");
```

since you are using empty strings as key, it returns the first one with the "" key...

so try to put values like :

```
b.putInt("ID",id);
b.putInt("NAME",name);
```

Comment: BUT, you're better off referencing a String constant, and hopefully a public one that that the receiver of the bundle can reference when pulling the value out.  Hard-coded strings in multiple places = bad.